# Sendkeys not working in pop window

Tags: selenium

In login pop window i can click elements and pass data using sendkeys to username but I am unable to pass data using sendkeys to password field. both are in same form and finding element by id but for username field it is working not working for password field.

Comment: Where's you code?  See [ask]

Comment: Also, I would add the tag 'sendkeys' to your question,